# Accessing JSON encoded PHP Array in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have an PHP Array which is formatted in the following format :

```
$jsonArray = array(
    "facebook" => array("user" => "8", "user_id" => "10", "user_post" => "6"),
    "twitter" => array("user" => "8", "user_id" => "10", "user_post" => "6")
);
```

I've then done the following so I can access the array

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.MyArray = ".json_encode($jsonArray).";</script>";
```

And to access the array I tried the following

```
alert(window.MyArray['facebook'][0]['user']);
```

yet that's seemed to fail, any directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.MyArray['facebook'][0]['user']
--------------------------^^^
```

Why do you need `[0]` here?

Use this:

```
window.MyArray['facebook']['user']
```

`MyArray` gives this:

```
{
    "facebook": {
        "user": "8",
        "user_id": "10",
        "user_post": "6"
    },
    "twitter": {
        ...
    }
}
```

`MyArray['facebook']` results in the following array:

```
{
    "user": "8",
    "user_id": "10",
    "user_post": "6"
}
```

Therefore, `MyArray['facebook']['user']` results in `8`.

Comment: @Curtis You're welcome. Please accept this answer if it helped you/solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
alert(window.MyArray.facebook.user);
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the json as a string, you need to convert it to an object. To do that you can use http://www.json.org/js.html